# ORACLE ORA-12505 after network IP addres change

Tags: oracle, database-administration

we have a situation here. We are all working on a database installed into a virtual machine running on our laptops. The virtual machine is naturally configured to use NAT networking and all goes well.

We need to move this VM because its very RAM consuming and we found another machine to place it.

The new machine have an IP into a different subnet but is perfectly reachable by our laptops. 
We configured the VM to use Bridged nwetorking so VM now have the same IP of the other subnet.

The guest OS is perfectly reachable from network so this is not a problem.

When I connect to VM's Oracle  I obtain an ORA-12505  ... 
Since I'm not a dba how to configure oracle to listen correctly from the new subnet ??

Thank in advance

EDIT:

another clue: when I connect to the VM and with the oracle user I give a LSNRCTL services I obtain
TNS-12541 no listener

When I switch back to the OLD subnet ALL works fine

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!! The problem was on linux OPEN SUSE ! The network name was set to change according to DHCP.. The network name was not found on tnsnames.ora and the service did not start

Removing the option to change name according to DHCP all now seems to work properly